# show image-button inside a GXT text field

Tags: gwt, gxt

is there a way to implement this kind of component with GXT API?

the image needs to be inside the text field. it must react to mouse clicks and must have its own tooltip. 
[image]

Comment: Like ComboBox and DateField do? These inherit from TriggerField, and the icon is called a trigger. There is also a TwinTriggerField, for when two such icons are required (can be over/under like SpinnerField or side by side).

Comment: By using gwt Image img=new Image("location of image"). we can add to the combobox i think.

Comment: TriggerField seems like the way to go. I'll post the results soon.